# Finding SVD of a Matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, svd

If $a_{1},a_{2} \in \mathcal{R}^{2},$ $\ \|a_{1}\|_{2} = \|a_{2}\|_{2} = K$, and the angle $\theta$ between $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ is between $0$ and $\pi/2$, we want to compute the SVD of the matrix $A = [a_{1},a_{2}],$ i.e. the vectors $a_{1}, a_{2}$ are the columns of $A$.

We know that $a_{2} = Ra_{1}$, where $R$ is a rotation matrix. If $Pa_{2} = a_{1}$, then $(I-P)a_{2}$ is orthogonal to $a_{1}$, where $P = R^{-1}$. But I am not sure how to use these to form an SVD of $A$...

Answer (score 2):

We seek the SVD $A = U\Sigma V^*$.
Note that
$$
A^*A = U(\Sigma\Sigma^*) U^* = 
\pmatrix
{\langle a_1,a_1 \rangle & \langle a_2,a_1 \rangle\\
\langle a_1,a_2 \rangle & \langle a_2,a_2 \rangle
}
=
K^2\pmatrix
{1 & \cos\theta\\
\cos \theta & 1
}
$$
This allows you to find $U$ and $\Sigma$ (by finding a spectral decomposition of the above).  From there, note that
$$
V = A^{-1} U \Sigma
$$
Or, the easier to compute
$$
V = [\Sigma^{-1}U^*A]^*
$$
To be sure, your singular values will be $\sigma_1 = \sqrt{1 + \cos \theta}$ and $\sigma_2 = \sqrt{1 - \cos \theta}$, and
$$
U = 
\frac 1{\sqrt 2}
\pmatrix{
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
}
$$